# How to access deleted native functions like fetch, XMLHTTPRequest?

Tags: javascript

How can I access previously deleted native functions? Where is its immutable origin? Where can I re-clone it from? How can I access `WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope.fetch` if `window.fetch` not exists/ is overridden?

Example

```
delete fetch; //or
fetch = manuallyModifiedFetchFunction;


(function(){
   "use strict";

   //I still would like to use the native function in this scope
   fetch("...");
})()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar questions were asked before and so far using `contentWindow` property of an `<iframe>` seems to be most reliable way.

```
let frame = document.createElement('iframe');
//hide the iframe
frame.style.display = 'none'; 

//Must add iframe to DOM, otherwise contentWindow would be null. 
document.body.appendChild(frame);

//lose built in fetch
fetch = () =>{};

//retrieve fetch from contentWindow property
window.fetch = frame.contentWindow.fetch;

//use fetch
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(res=>res.json())
  .then(json=>console.log(json))
  .catch(err=>console.log('Error!'));
```